# Mail_Mbox() PEAR script - load mbox message from string instead of file

Tags: php, email, pear, mbox

It works great if I try to load from a file, but I'm working with mbox formatted messages previously stored in a MySQL table. I've loaded the message into a $variable and for whatever reason it doesn't want to accept it. Any ideas?

Sample code:

```
<?php
    // Reads a mbox file
    #$mbox = new Mail_Mbox('test.mbox');        // Works
    $mbox = new Mail_Mbox($data);               // Doesn't work (what the heck?!)
    $mbox->open();

    $message = $mbox->get(0);

    $decodedMessage = new Mail_mimeDecode($message, "\r\n");
    $structuredMessage = $decodedMessage->decode(
        array(
            'include_bodies'    =>  true,
            'decode_bodies'     =>  true
        )
    );
?>
```

Everything's working except loading a message into this script from a string, as opposed to a file. Totally lost on this.

For reference:
http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mbox

**SOLUTION EXAMPLE THAT WORKS:**

```
<?php
    // Setup a Stream_Var() to let us use a $variable like a file...so that Mail_Mbox() works
    stream_wrapper_register( "var", "Stream_Var" );

    // Reads a mbox file
    $mbox = new Mail_Mbox('var://GLOBALS/this-is-my-variable');   // Leave the $ off
    $mbox->open();

    $message = $mbox->get(0);

    $decodedMessage = new Mail_mimeDecode($message, "\r\n");
    $structuredMessage = $decodedMessage->decode(
        array(
            'include_bodies'    =>  true,
            'decode_bodies'     =>  true
        )
    );
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation states](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mbox.mail-mbox.mail-mbox.php):

> void constructor Mail_Mbox::Mail_Mbox ( string $file )

The class does *not* accept strings, only files.

You might want to try a stream wrapper like [Stream_Var](http://pear.php.net/package/Stream_Var) to make the variable accessible like a file. Maybe it works. If it does not, open a feature request in the PEAR bugtracker.